# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'file.txt', 'w'"

Tags: python, list, filenotfounderror

Trying to save list `blizzard` to a text file in current directory. Unfortunately, Python 3 spits out a `FileNotFoundError` error. What's causing this error, and how can I fix it? I'm confused because I'm not trying to read an existing file, I'm making a new one, so why output an error like this? Thank you so much.

```
import os

blizzard = [1,2,3,4,5]

with open(f"'blizzard.txt', 'w'") as file:
    for row in blizzard:
        s = " ".join(map(str, row))
        file.write(s+'\n')
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\facrec\Desktop\snow\ice\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(f"'blizzard.txt', 'w'") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'blizzard.txt', 'w'"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where the code says `f"'blizzard.txt', 'w'"`, what do you expect the `f` to mean? What effect do you expect the double quotes to have? According to your understanding, how many strings are written here? According to your understanding, how many arguments should be passed to `open` in order to do what you want? In the future, please try to read and understand error messages, look at the code carefully, and [approach the problem analytically](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: In this case, the error message contains the necessary hint: `No such file or directory: "'blizzard.txt', 'w'"`. Presumably, you did not intend the file name to contain `'` symbols or a comma, and you did not intend it to end with `'w'`. This should tip you off that the code is not specifying the file name that you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you Karl for this amazing explanation. There are two strings here. I thought that `blizzard.txt` should be enclosed with single quotes, and `w` should also be enclosed with single quotes, and then everything inside the parentheses of `open()` would be enclosed with double quotes for f-string to work. Two arguments would pass to `open()`: filename and writing of list to file.

Comment: "and then everything inside the parentheses of open() would be enclosed with double quotes for f-string to work. " I can't understand what you want the f-string to do in the first place, since there are no `{}` placeholders anywhere. But also, quotes are not like brackets; they don't nest. They are **only** part of the syntax for saying where **a string** begins or ends. An f-string is **just** a string that gets `.format` called on it ahead of time. If you have two strings that you want to be f-strings, then you... prefix each one with `f` separately. But neither of these needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

You have the file name and mode surrounded with extra, erroneous quotes which make it a single string.

```
open(f"'blizzard.txt', 'w'")
```

should be

```
open('blizzard.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Shouldn't we close these as typos?